# Check if any row has the same values as a numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am working with a `pandas.Dataframe` that looks as follows:

```
       A  B  C  D
index
    1  0  0  0  1
    2  1  0  0  1 
    3  ... 
    4  ... 
    ...
```

And I am creating a `numpy.arrays` that have the same shape as a row within this dataframe. I want to check if the array I am creating 'is present' within the dataframe.
In this case, for example, my array would look like this, if it **is in the dataframe**:

```
  a=  [0,0,0,1]
```

**It is not** if it looks like this:

```
b = [1,1,1,1]
```

Any help, even if it is a link to the right answer, is much appreciated as I have looked through stackoverflow and fortunately I did not miss anything.

Comment: IIUC: `df.eq(a).all(1).any()` to check if any rows are the same as `a`.  To find the first row index in which it is true: `df.eq(a).all(1).idxmax()`. To get all rows where it is true (this might be scary if you have many columns in your actual data): `df.loc[df.groupby([*df]).groups[(*a,)]]`

Comment: What is the datatype of the array ? There is some effort required to make it work for floats since comparison isn't trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0, 1, 0, 0],
                   'B':[0, 0, 1, 1],
                   'C':[0, 0, 0, 0],
                   'D':[1, 1, 0, 1]})


#    A  B  C  D
# 0  0  0  0  1
# 1  1  0  0  1
# 2  0  1  0  0
# 3  0  1  0  1 



>>> a = [0, 0, 0, 1]
>>> (df == a).all(axis=1).any()
True

>>> b = [1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> (df == b).all(axis=1).any()
False
```